# Xcode: Could not attach to pid: "####"

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I am trying to build an iOS app into the actual device and I get this error. The app seems to be stuck at the launch screen.

I have tried restarting Xcode but it still didn't work.

I have already open developer mode by below command as well.

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Comment: Try in from terminal `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable`

Comment: try resetting your iOS Simulator, can often help resolve such issues in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this from **Teminal**

`sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable`

Source
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120282

Or else restart the device and reconnect it once again.